# If it's about 'wall' of our house, is it 'empty' or 'plain'?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

I was tweeting Lenovo for a context, but then dithered over which word to use. I wanted to say that one of the walls of our house does not have any picture, artifact, clock or anything that we do on the wall.

What that wall is?

> We have kept one of our room's walls ***empty OR plain?***

I wonder whether we can use 'empty' for something that is not a box-type of thing or any bench.

---

Another question, if the wall is not painted, is it 'plain' wall?

Comment: Empty is acceptable, but I would say 'bare'

Comment: Spot on, sir! @StoneyB bare walls -undecorated walls. I always used 'empty' instead.

Comment: If there is absolutely no paint on the wall, what is there? Exposed sheetrock? Bricks? In general you could describe a wall as _unpainted_ and your meaning would be carried just fine, but if you want to be descriptive you’ll need to say what is _there_ (not what is missing).

Answer (score 3):

Your "box" analogy is very good. In the US we would say that a "room is empty", but a wall is *bare.*  *Plain* has other meanings which might confuse the issue - for example, when one is describing a home, *plain* is often used to mean "austere", or without ornamentation. So, if you visited the home of an Amish person in Pennsylvania, the walls could have hooks for coats and hats, and a clock, and even a curtain over the window, and still be described as "plain".

Answer (score 0):

Such a wall is empty. It looks empty. And it is empty of 'any picture, artifact, clock or anything' else we hang on a wall.

At least that is the usage I have inherited from my forebears.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term *blank*.  That is,

> We have kept one of our walls *blank*.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "bare".  If you said "plain", I would assume a drab color.

Answer (score 0):

If the wall is not painted, it is "unpainted" or "unfinished".  Instead of "unfinished", it might be "brick" or "concrete" or "cement" or "natural wood" or "stone" -- by default, these (finished) surfaces are unpainted.

In most American homes, the interior walls have the following layers, from the surface inward:

- Paint (most newer homes use water-soluble acrylic paints)
- Primer (most newer homes use Kilz or polyvinyl acetate primer)
- Texturizer or "skim coats" of plaster.  The most common texture looks like the texture of an orange peel.  "Skim coats" of plaster are designed to achieve a very smooth finish.
- gypsum board (aka Sheetrock) or a similar water-resistant material.  The non-water-resistant material includes:

  -- A thick paper-like surface layer.

  -- A pre-cured plaster-like material.

  -- Another thick paper-like surface layer.
- Wood studs, separated by either insulation or air.